# Matplotlib: Saved files in a loop aren't the same as in show()

Tags: python, matplotlib

My program shows the correct graph in the `plt.show()` pop up but not in the *fig.savefig* one. I'm quite new to python so apologies if it is something simple.
I'm using *python 2.7.10, windows (10)*.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('strike_details.txt')  #, skip_header= 0
header= 3
information=10000
width = 5
files = 16
types = 4

length = information + header
frames = data[header:length,0]

fig= plt.figure()
plt.grid(True)

for i in range(0,int(files)):
    density=data[(header+i*length):(length+i*length),4]
    plt.plot(frames,density, label=data[i*length+1][2])

    for j in range (0,files/types):
        if i==(types*(j+1)-1):  
            plt.legend(loc='best')
            plt.xlabel('$Frames$', fontsize=22)
            plt.ylabel('$Density$', fontsize=22)
            fig.savefig(str(data[j*length+1][0])+'_'+str(data[j*length+1][1])+'_'+str(data[j*length+1][2])+'.png',format='png', dpi=fig.dpi)        
            plt.show()
            plt.clf()
```

The program produces four files with different file names but they're all of the first group you see in the plt.show pop up.

If I missed out anything important let me know.

Thanks,

Lio

Comment: How many plot windows pop up?

Comment: Four, one at a time. (As in one window pops up, close that and the next does)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is due to mixing the API-style and interactive-styles of matplotlib. When you call `plt.show()` the link between the active figure and `fig` is broken, and so you continue to output the first figure you created. I can reproduce this problem with this minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

for n in range(0,10):
    plt.plot(list(range(0,n)))
    fig.savefig('test%d.png' % n)
    plt.show() 
    plt.clf()
```

If you remove the `show()` the issue goes away.

The correct way to do this is to access the current interactive figure via `plt.gcf()`:

```
plt.gcf().savefig(...)
```

Alternatively, you can workaround it by recreating the figure object on each loop:

```
for i in range(0,int(files)):
    fig= plt.figure()
    plt.grid(True)
    ...
```